# Quering history of network interface in zabbix server return empty set?

Tags: sql, zabbix, interface, query

I've installed **Zabbix** on **Ubuntu**.

Although I can see a "**graph**" and related "**latest data"** for all network interfaces in Zabbix front-end, there is no data for them when I directly query MySQL database!!!!

```
mysql>select value from history where itemid=**23717**

Empty set(0.00 sec)
```

**23717** is one of the itemid's for my **network interfaces**.

actually there are lots of info in front-end (graph & latest data) but the query return no value.

however another itemid i.e "cpu usage" is OK.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying the wrong table - that item is probably set to be "Numeric (unsigned)", and you should query the `history_uint` table instead.

Comment: thank u so much, exactly. i'm so happy. thank u so muuuuuuuuuuch